# Handle a "NoClassDefFoundError"?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

Is there a way I could ignore a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError like try catch where it calls the missing class? I dont need to fix the missing classes because this is part of my program.

Comment: Can you share any code with us?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` comes when the class is not available at run time in classpath. If it is not present then how can you expect it to call the missing class.

Comment: @BeginnersSake No i want the code to keep going and not stop/crash, I just want it to ignore the code where it calls the missing clas

Comment: @William Taco you can try to create user defined exceptions in your case.

Comment: Yes but you need to understand how classloading works. Look into `Class.forName(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont need to fix the missing classes because this is part of my program.

I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here but you should be able to `catch` a `NoClassDefFoundError` to prevent your JVM from crashing. Let `A` be a class that *has-a* reference to `B`. If `B.class` is not available at runtime, you can handle the `NoClassDefFoundError` as follows :

```
class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            A a = new A();
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            //log the error or take some action
        }

        System.out.println("All good here, lets continue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear how this would compile if the `A` class isn't defined

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't completely follow. I don't seem to mention that `A` class is not defined in my answer. Did you mean `B.class`?

Comment: Probably, yes. I must've skipped the explanation

Comment: @cricket_007 Yup. `B.class` was available during compilation but not available in the `classpath` at runtime.

Comment: @Winter *Let A be a class that has-a reference to B. If B.class is not available at runtime, you can handle the NoClassDefFoundError*. Do I really need to show the `B` class? Let your imagination assume `B` to have whatever code you like.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks. I intentionally skipped adding `B` to show that it is missing.